# how could I change the IP address dynamically

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vps, ubuntu-14.04

I bought many IPs for my VPS machine.

But I don't get how to change the IP with the interface eth0, eth1.

And it seems only eth0, eth1 can be seem with ifconfig

And the machine will lose connection if I type `sudo ifconfig eth1 133.130.60.37` under ssh connection.

Any idea to switch my machine IP ?

## This is my network interfaces

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
accept_ra 1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 133.130.60.33
gateway 133.130.60.1
netmask 255.255.254.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
address 133.130.60.36
gateway 133.130.60.1
netmask 255.255.254.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4


auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
address 133.130.60.37
gateway 133.130.60.1
netmask 255.255.254.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4


auto eth4
iface eth4 inet static
address 133.130.60.38
gateway 133.130.60.1
netmask 255.255.254.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eth5
iface eth5 inet static
address 133.130.60.39
gateway 133.130.60.1
netmask 255.255.254.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

[image]

Comment: you can have multiple IP on the same interface. The configuration to be made depends of your goal. You can use the program "ip" to add / remove IP addresses on an interface.

Comment: @JFL im so appreciate your reply, could you explain it more detail ? if i want to change ip on eth1 , can i just type `sudo ifconfig eth1 133.130.60.37` ? but i tried it and it failed :(

Comment: Do you actually have six network interfaces? That seems rather unlikely.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i was wrong, there are only eth0 and eth1